# PostSharp Detected .NET Core SDK 7

Tags: .net-6.0, postsharp

I have a project targeting NET 6.0 framework.
When I build the project, I’m getting this message

Warning
Detected .NET Core SDK 7.0.100. This SDK version was not tested on this version of PostSharp. Using it may result in a build failure. Supported SDK versions are 2.1.500 to 6.0 (any revision).

Here is my project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="PostSharp.Patterns.Model" Version="6.10.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0">
      <TreatAsUsed>true</TreatAsUsed>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Building project in visual studio 2022

Comment: What is your question? Your version of PostSharp is only testet for the .NET SDK versions  2.1.500 to 6.0 and you are using version 7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update PostSharp to version 2023.0.3. It supports .NET 7 SDK.

The fact that your project targets .NET 6 doesn't imply that .NET 6 SDK is going to be used to build your project. [By default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), the highest installed SDK is used, unless you [configure otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) using [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) configuration file.